# ¿Porqué RequestAnimationFrame se encuentra al inicio y no al final?

Tags: javascript

estoy estuve creando mi propia versión de un reloj que observe en la web hecho en en html - css - js, hasta ahora todo funciono pero hay una sección donde realmente funciona pero no entiendo porque RequestAnimationFrame se debe colocar al principio de la función recursiva y no al final, siendo esta una función recursiva, ¿no debería llamarse a la función recursiva al final para así de esta manera lograr la ejecución de todo el cuerpo de la función y luego que se vuelva a ejecutar?.

```
const clockSetup = () => {
  const $elements = document.querySelectorAll('.digitgroup');
  

  const clock = (() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(clock);
    const $digitGroups = $elements;
    let date = new Date();

    const time = [ date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()]
    .map(n => `0${n}`.slice(-2).split('').map(e => +e))
    .reduce((acc, n) => acc.concat(n), []);
    
    time.forEach((n, index) => {
      const $digits = $digitGroups[index].children;

      for(let i = 0; i < $digits.length; i++){
        if(i !== n){
          $digits[i].classList.remove('white');
        }
        $digits[n].classList.add('white');
      }
    });
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(clock);
}
```

Comment: En ese código realmente no tiene importancia que se llame al inicio o al final. Si tienes un delta que usas como discriminador para saber cuándo seguir ejecutando y cuándo no el loop, tendría sentido ponerlo al final.

Comment: Podrías colocar algún ejemplo o ser un poco más explicito, disculpa.